# Apache Tomcat 9 rewrite valve not working

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting

I have been trying to setup my tomcat 9 rewrite valve (on global level) without success, followed every tutorial I have found on the internet, but no matter how i configure my rewirte.config the valve simply does NOT work.

So I write the simplest rewrite.config I can think of, which contains only a single line:

```
RewriteRule ^test$ manager/test.jpg
```

So this rule simply means to rewrite http://localhost:8080/test to http://localhost:8080/manager/test.jpg

This file is placed inside $CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost
I have verified that the valve is loaded properly in the localhost.2018-08-30.log log file:

```
30-Aug-2018 14:32:43.530 FINE [main] org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.parse Add rule with pattern ^test$ and substitution manager/test.jpg
```

However when I restarted tomcat and tested it, the URL http://localhost:8080/test gave me a 404 error while the URL http://localhost:8080/manager/test.jpg loads the actual image correctly.

The access log shows:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2018:14:39:50 +0800] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 1078
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2018:14:42:34 +0800] "GET /manager/test.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

So what did I miss?

Comment: okay i found the answer to my own problem, what i miss is a single backslash "/" in my rewrite.config

instead of:
RewriteRule ^test$ manager/test.jpg

it should be:
RewriteRule ^/test$ /manager/test.jpg