# Tomcat Remove index.php Codeiginter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, tomcat

I create website for Class-Project by using Codeigniter and want to remove index.php from URL.

I follow [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url) . It's work well in local server. But when I'm upload file to server that using Tomcat9 it doesn't work.

I'm found .htaccess doesn't work with tomcat right?

So how can I remove index.php from URL?

Comment: Are you sure you want to / have to use Tomcat for this? It's an unusual choice for a PHP project

Comment: The reason I use Tomcat because my TA provide this server for class-project. I have no choice.

Comment: Tomcat has a rewrite valve and the rewrite rules have the same syntax as Apache https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/rewrite.html The rules must be put in a file called rewrite.config, an internet search brings up examples like https://stackoverflow.com/q/52090777/318758

Answer (score 1):

You can remove index.php and set some thing else like question mark.
Go to 
application->config->config.php 
and set 
`$config['index_page'] = '?'` .